# What is the relationship among batch-size, sequence-length and hidden_size?

Tags: dynamic, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

When reading the API document of dynamic_rnn, I have the following question:

Are there constraints on the relationship among batch-size, sequence-length and (cell)hidden_size?

I am thinking that:

sequence-length <= (cell)hidden_size, or,

batch-size * sequence-length <= (cell)hidden_size

Am I correct? I have been reading through a lot of web pages but couldn't find an answer.

Thanks all.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn

Example:

```
# create a BasicRNNCell
rnn_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(hidden_size)

# 'outputs' is a tensor of shape [batch_size, max_time, cell_state_size]

# defining initial state
initial_state = rnn_cell.zero_state(batch_size, dtype=tf.float32)

# 'state' is a tensor of shape [batch_size, cell_state_size]
outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(rnn_cell, input_data,
                                   initial_state=initial_state,
                                   dtype=tf.float32)
# create 2 LSTMCells
rnn_layers = [tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(size) for size in [128, 256]]

# create a RNN cell composed sequentially of a number of RNNCells
multi_rnn_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(rnn_layers)

# 'outputs' is a tensor of shape [batch_size, max_time, 256]
# 'state' is a N-tuple where N is the number of LSTMCells containing a
# tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMStateTuple for each cell
outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=multi_rnn_cell,
                                   inputs=data,
                                   dtype=tf.float32)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no relationship as far as the API is concerned. Fix any two of these parameters and the remaining can still be any non-negative integer (or, in the case of `sequence_length`, any `batch_size`-length vector of non-negative integers).

The resulting model may overfit very easily if `hidden_size` is huge and there's very little training data, but it will still work. Note that training data is usually presented in mini-batches, so the amount of training data won't be the sum of sequence lengths passed to `dynamic_rnn`.

There are also hardware constraints, as `batch_size` and the maximum sequence length affect memory usage.